# Contacts Storage process consumes more than 53% of battery life

Tags: contacts, battery-life, 5.0-lollipop, nexus-5, google-contacts

My battery doctor app points to "Contacts Storage" which is a native Android process as the chief consumer of battery life. Can't disable the process because no other app can reach or display my contacts when "contacts storage" is disabled.
Tried factory reset and things looked OK for the first week-two. Now it's back to consuming battery life like crazy.
Any app can replace this native horrid process?
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Battery Info stats are misleading. People see 53% and freak out. This number is based on the battery usage, and something has the be "the winner". Also, the stats are based off usage since the last time the battery was fully charged.

Battery stats are "cleared" when you charge your battery to full (or near full) then unplug it from the charger.

Now if your battery is discharging within an hour, then yes, you have some issue that is draining your battery.

If you have your device syncing contacts (like google+ and facebook) and you have a lot of contacts in those services, it could be the sync that is causing the usage. Doing clearing the data or cache of the Contacts storage is not going to help, as it will just require the service to re-sync contacts.